# How to remove earliest/latest row by two columns (userId, StatusCheck)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have crosschex database that is used to store logged in/out data. Sometimes it happens that user clock in/out few times. I would like to remove that duplicates leaving the earliest when log in and latest when log out.
Here is what I have:

```
USE crosschex;
SELECT UI.Name, INOUT.UserId, INOUT.CheckTime, S.StatusText
FROM dbo.Checkinout AS INOUT
INNER JOIN dbo.Userinfo AS UI ON
INOUT.Userid = UI.Userid
INNER JOIN dbo.Status AS S ON INOUT.CheckType = S.Statusid
WHERE 
    UI.Groupid = 1 AND INOUT.CheckTime >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) AND INOUT.CheckTime < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-3, 1)
```

Here is the result:

```
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 07:58:06.000"   "In"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 07:58:15.000"   "In"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 07:58:38.000"   "In"
"Kate B"    "4" "2018-05-04 14:15:45.000"   "In"
"Kate B"    "4" "2018-05-04 14:15:46.000"   "In"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:46.000"   "Out"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:48.000"   "Out"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:49.000"   "Out"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:50.000"   "Out"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:51.000"   "Out"
"Patty" "5" "2018-05-04 20:31:36.000"   "Out"
```

What I would like is to remove the earliest and lattest for each userId and StatusText In/Oou to get that:

```
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 07:58:06.000"   "In"
"Kate B"    "4" "2018-05-04 14:15:45.000"   "In"
"Zeab Simon"    "6" "2018-05-04 16:34:51.000"   "Out"
"Patty" "5" "2018-05-04 20:31:36.000"   "Out"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: When you post questions like this, it's really helpful if you format the sample data as inserts, so people can pick right up and not have to hassle with creating tables and generating the DDL themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, I did the following.

```
CREATE TABLE shift (worker_name VARCHAR(25), worker_id INTEGER, shift_time TIMESTAMP, in_out VARCHAR(3));

INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 07:58:06.000', 'In');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 07:58:15.000', 'In');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 07:58:38.000', 'In');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Kate B',     4, '2018-05-04 14:15:45.000', 'In');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Kate B',     4, '2018-05-04 14:15:46.000', 'In');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 16:34:46.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 16:34:48.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 16:34:49.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 16:34:50.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Zeab Simon', 6, '2018-05-04 16:34:51.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('Patty',      5, '2018-05-04 20:31:36.000', 'Out');
```

I then ran the following query:

```
SELECT worker_name, MIN(shift_time), in_out 
FROM shift 
WHERE in_out = 'In' 
GROUP BY worker_name, in_out
UNION
SELECT worker_name, MAX(shift_time), in_out 
FROM shift 
WHERE in_out = 'Out' 
GROUP BY worker_name, in_out
ORDER BY worker_name
```

Which gives:

```
worker_name,         shift_time,   in_out
Kate B       2018-05-04 14:15:45       In
Patty        2018-05-04 20:31:36      Out
Zeab Simon   2018-05-04 07:58:06       In
Zeab Simon   2018-05-04 16:34:51      Out
```

A cursory inspection reveals that these are the correct times - earliest clock_in and latest clock_out. A db-fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a3a68ebeb889e03a7e9d9607be0e85ab). To get the best answers to your questions, you might consider giving a fiddle in the question itself - help  us to help you!

Following the OP's clarifications in comments the need to delete extraneous records from the same table, I used the result above in a `CTE` (Common Table Expression - AKA the `WITH` clause) to delete the other records from the main shift table as follows.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT worker_name, worker_id,   
  MIN(shift_time) as shift_time, in_out   
  FROM shift 
  WHERE in_out = 'In'  
  GROUP BY worker_name, worker_id, in_out
  UNION
  SELECT worker_name, worker_id, 
  MAX(shift_time) as shift_time, in_out 
  FROM shift WHERE in_out = 'Out' GROUP 
  BY worker_name, worker_id, in_out
)
-- select * from cte  -- testing
DELETE FROM shift
WHERE shift_time NOT IN 
(
  SELECT shift_time FROM cte    
);
```

And then a simple `SELECT` in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=33c66fb5132793a5cbc6487f3819fcfb) shows that the correct result has been achieved.

Another solution was kindly provided by @ypercube [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/57ru6whNvUroGPyu8ezAvK/) - worth looking at for learning purposes. It is actually (no surprise here) more correct. My SQL will not work properly if there are **exactly** matching times for a `MAX`(or `MIN`) and a non significant value!

Comment: This is excellent answer. Very instructive and thank you for indications about how to post better questions. However your query select only desired result, and I would like to remove unnecessary rows.

Comment: I completed the problem 8-). If it's suitable, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a user only checks in/out once a day. There is no checking in/out for lunch brakes or similar. And no one works night shifts, so that the check out would be on the day after the check in. Further provided, that no user managed to check in/out twice in the same second, this might do it:

```
DELETE cioo
       FROM dbo.checkinout cioo
            INNER JOIN dbo.status so
                       ON so.statusid = cioo.checktype
       WHERE so.statustext = 'In'
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM dbo.checkinout cioi
                                WHERE cioi.userid = cioo.userid
                                      AND convert(date, cioi.checktime) = convert(date, cioo.checktime)
                                      AND cioi.checktime < cioo.checktime)
             OR so.statustext = 'Out'
                AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                   FROM dbo.checkinout cioi
                                   WHERE cioi.userid = cioo.userid
                                         AND convert(date, cioi.checktime) = convert(date, cioo.checktime)
                                         AND cioi.checktime > cioo.checktime);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could number the rows using an specific order and delete those rows where row number > 1.

Let me suggest to add a unique or primary key to the query just avoid using:

```
ON   X.worker_id = s.worker_id
AND  X.shift_time = s.shift_time
AND  X.in_out = s.in_out
```

```
WITH X AS
(
    SELECT   *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_id, in_out ORDER BY worker_id, shift_time) rn
    FROM     shift
)
DELETE s
FROM shift s
JOIN X
ON   X.worker_id = s.worker_id
AND  X.shift_time = s.shift_time
AND  X.in_out = s.in_out
AND  x.rn > 1;
```

This is the final result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM shift;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> worker_name | worker_id | shift_time          | in_out
> :---------- | --------: | :------------------ | :-----
> Zeab Simon  |         6 | 04/05/2018 07:58:06 | In    
> Kate B      |         4 | 04/05/2018 14:15:45 | In    
> Zeab Simon  |         6 | 04/05/2018 16:34:46 | Out   
> Patty       |         5 | 04/05/2018 20:31:36 | Out
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a230a3a9eedea244011d01444f0986d)*